# Elixir Accumulator List of Maps

Tags: erlang, elixir

Can you help me to implement one Accumulator from List of maps?.

```
[
 %{
    score: 1,
    name: "Javascript",
 },
 %{
    score: 2,
    name: "Elixir",
 },
 %{
    score: 10,
    name: "Elixir",
 }
]
```

The result should be:

```
[
    %{
        score: 12,
        name: "Elixir",
    },
    %{
        score: 1,
        name: "Javascript",
    }
]
```

I will appreciate your suggestion.

Regards

Comment: When asking these sorts of questions, you should share whatever research you've done and any code you've already tried. As it stands right now, it appears (no doubt incorrectly) that you didn't make any effort to solve your own problem before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your original list is stored in `input` local variable, one might start with [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#reduce/3) using [`Map.update/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#update/4) as a reducer.

```rb
Enum.reduce(input, %{}, fn %{score: score, name: name}, acc ->
  Map.update(acc, name, score, & &1 + score)
end)
#⇒ %{"Elixir" => 12, "Javascript" => 1}
```

Whether you insist on having a list of maps as a result (which is way less readable IMSO,) go further and [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#map/2) the result:

```rb
Enum.map(%{"Elixir" => 12, "Javascript" => 1}, fn {name, score} ->
  %{name: name, score: score}
end)
#⇒ [%{name: "Elixir", score: 12},
#   %{name: "Javascript", score: 1}]
```

---

To sum it up:

```rb
input
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn %{score: score, name: name}, acc ->
  Map.update(acc, name, score, & &1 + score)
end)
|> Enum.map(& %{name: elem(&1, 0), score: elem(&1, 1)})
#⇒ [%{name: "Elixir", score: 12},
#   %{name: "Javascript", score: 1}]
```

---

*Sidenote:* *maps* in [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) (and, hence, in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir)) are *not ordered*. That means, if you want the resulting list to be sorted by `name`, or by `score`, you should explicitly [`Enum.sort/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort/2) it:

```rb
Enum.sort(..., & &1.score > &2.score)
#⇒ [%{name: "Elixir", score: 12},
#   %{name: "Javascript", score: 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks one more time

Answer (score 1):

A simple way could be to use [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3) to group the items by name, then [`Enum.sum/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sum/1) to sum the scores:

```elixir
list
|> Enum.group_by(& &1.name, & &1.score)
|> Enum.map(fn {name, score} -> %{name: name, score: Enum.sum(score)} end)
```

Output:

```elixir
[%{name: "Elixir", score: 12}, %{name: "Javascript", score: 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were looking to create & use a more generalized solution, you could create your own Merger module.

```rb
defmodule Merger do
  def merge_by(enumerable, name_fun, merge_fun) do
    enumerable
    |> Enum.group_by(name_fun)
    |> Enum.map(fn {_name, items} -> Enum.reduce(items, merge_fun) end)
  end
end

list = [
 %{score: 1, name: "Javascript"},
 %{score: 2, name: "Elixir"},
 %{score: 10, name: "Elixir"}
]

Merger.merge_by(list, & &1.name, &%{&1 | score: &1.score + &2.score})
# => [%{name: "Elixir", score: 12}, %{name: "Javascript", score: 1}]
```